# What is the meaning of "Las bastardillas" in this context?

Tags: etimología, escritura-manuscrita

I came across a quote that had a word italicized, followed by the parenthetical explanation that "*the italics are ours*" (the italics are mine there). This is common. But it said (in Spanish), "Los bastardillas son nuestras" (the italics were theirs there).

I thought the word for italics was "cursiva"; and the word "bastarda" means "bastard"

So: why was "bastardilla" use here instead of "cursiva" and, is there some connection between italics and bastards and, if so, what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are almost synonyms. `Cursiva` can also mean handwriting, while `bastardilla` means just printed letters resembling handwriting (slanted to the right, etc.).

`Letra bastardilla` comes from `letra bastarda`, which was how cursive handwriting was called.

Nowadays, everyday software has popularized `cursiva` and `itálica` at the expense of `bastardilla`, which remains as a somewhat obscure technical term.

See  [es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastardilla](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastardilla)

Comment: +1, tho a source would be nice. Here's the wikipedia article on the term: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastardilla